# Is it possible to measure the openstack load with ganglia monitoring system?

Tags: cloud, openstack, ganglia

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to measure load on openstack say for ex CPU usage measurement on slave/child openstack VMs with Ganglia monitoring system? I could not find any proper answers for this. Here I am using separate servers for measuring the load and for running VMs.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've monitored openstack with ganglia.  howver over time i've noticed ganglia tends to get filled with noise and you just tend to lose a lot of value from it.  I'd not use ganglia again for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically, yes - although using it easily and "out of the box" with no twaeking might be troublesome. Adding a ganglia agent to each of your openstack compute nodes is where you'd want to start, and from there its very dependent on what openstack network configuration youre using and if multicast is directly viable between all your nodes.

That will give you the hypervisor host details. If you want the details of the VMs themselves, you're better using a plugin to get data from Libvirt (im assuming a KVM based openstack here, not the other hypervisors) for best/most honest numbers, although you could also run ganglia agents inside your VMs as well. Again, how they communicate (i.e. is multicast available) will detemine how easy/hard it is to get functioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can also explore possibility of Nagios for monitoring. There is a plugin for ceilometer in nagios.
ref: http://blog.zhaw.ch/icclab/nagios-ceilometer-integration-new-plugin-available/